# How to modify browser window url from facebook page app (iframe)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a shared url that land into facebook page app, with app_data
ex:

```
https://www.facebook.com/?...&app_data=10 (this url is the browser window url)
```

However, I notice, if I click on any link in this page, it will still pull the content from the shared url.

My plan is to reset the browser window url (without the app_data), and present another content to the user.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done, window main url and facebook canvas iframe url are different.